# is there a different way to access AD (Windows Active Directory Authentication) in android platform instead of LDAP/Azure

Tags: android, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I can do like can pass username and password to the Windows service and from service can go to AD but that's not a good approach because it may lead to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is anyway not supported in Azure.
If you use Windows Server 2012 R2, I would suggest installing [ADFS 3.0 and configuring OAuth protocol](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html).

After completing ADFS setup, you can use [ADAL for Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android). [Here is a good sample code for that](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Android).

And you will have all the modern security protocols and standards in place.

As alternative, you can use [Azure AD with Active Directory Synchronisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790204.aspx). And use same ADAL for Andriod to authenticate with Azure AD. Azure AD Sync is supported starting Windows Server 2008 and newer (so elliminate the requirements for WIndows Server 2012 R2 and ADFS 3.0).

Please note that Azure AD Synchronisation is part of the **free* tier of Azure AD (up to 500k objects in the Azure AD), which makes it really attractive.